# How to detect if game is hidden?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'd like to pause my game when my app is hidden (user pressed home button or changed app). How can I detect that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ApplicationListener` interface has a `pause` method that gets called when your app is losing focus, that's where you need to hook in logic to stop doing any game logic.